# how to separate macid and timestamp wlan address uisng python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, text, text-processing

I am doing text-processing I want separate the mac id, timestamp and also every data will separate with a column, please help me how do it .
I have data like this.

```
2019-01-12T00:15:16+00:00 12.68.73.170 syslog: eventd_to_syslog():User[b0:19:c6:11:c5:11] leave WLAN[Fairfield_GUEST] at AP[BBCFIAP02-01-BREAKFAST@0c:f4:d5:1a:7e:50] with Session Time[3259.59 sec] RX Bytes[7056295] TX Bytes[355485553] 
2019-01-12T00:16:53+00:00 12.68.73.170 syslog: eventd_to_syslog():User[b0:19:c6:11:c5:11] leave WLAN[Fairfield_GUEST] at AP[BBCFIAP04-01-WORK_AREA@d8:38:fc:2a:6b:10] with Session Time[12.89 sec] RX Bytes[2369] TX Bytes[2128]
```

I tried this :

```
f = open('C:\\Users\\NanduCn\\Desktop\\project\\input_text_file.data')
for word in f.read().split():
    print(word)
```

I want to output like this.

```
datetime            controller_ip   module  usermac         event    ssid           apname          apmac           sessiontime rxbytes txbytes

2019-01-12 00:37.0  12.68.73.170    syslog  40:98:ad:b5:87:11   leave    Fairfield_GUEST    BBCFIAP09-03-RM316  e8:1d:a8:04:02:60   39.16       189158  2115189
20
```

please help me how to do it.

Comment: I've edited my answer, it will hopefully solve your problem. Also, I can't really fix the variable of `T00:15:16+00:00`, but I'm sure you can convert it into the required format

Answer (score 0):

You could try this out:

```
(?P<Date>[\d\-]+)(?P<Time>[a-zA-Z\d:\+]+)\s*(?P<IP>[\d\.]+)\s*(?P<Module>[a-zA-Z\d]+)\s*(?:.+?)\[(?P<Usermac>[a-zA-Z\d\:]+)\]\s*(?P<Event>[\w]+).+?\[(?P<SSID>[\w]+)\].+?\[(?P<APname>[\w\-0-9]+)\@(?P<APmac>[\w\:0-9]+)\].+?\[(?P<sessiontime>[\w\.]+)\s*.+?\].+?\[(?P<rxbytes>[0-9a-zA-Z]+)\].+?\[(?P<txbytes>[0-9a-zA-Z]+)\]
```

As seen here: **[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/6GjiGi/1)**

## Explanation:

(*If you have any questions about the different pattern types used, you can refer https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html*)

I've used Named Capturing Groups a lot here, using `(?P<Name>stuff)` where `Name` denotes the name of the captured group like `SSID` and `Module` and stuff denotes whatever you want to capture.

Here's the code you'll require:

```
import re

text = """
2019-01-12T00:15:16+00:00 12.68.73.170 syslog: eventd_to_syslog():User[b0:19:c6:11:c5:11] leave WLAN[Fairfield_GUEST] at AP[BBCFIAP02-01-BREAKFAST@0c:f4:d5:1a:7e:50] with Session Time[3259.59 sec] RX Bytes[7056295] TX Bytes[355485553]
2019-01-12T00:16:53+00:00 12.68.73.170 syslog: eventd_to_syslog():User[b0:19:c6:11:c5:11] leave WLAN[Fairfield_GUEST] at AP[BBCFIAP04-01-WORK_AREA@d8:38:fc:2a:6b:10] with Session Time[12.89 sec] RX Bytes[2369] TX Bytes[2128]
"""
regex = r'(?P<Date>[\d\-]+)(?P<Time>[a-zA-Z\d:\+]+)\s*(?P<IP>[\d\.]+)\s*(?P<Module>[a-zA-Z\d]+)\s*(?:.+?)\[(?P<Usermac>[a-zA-Z\d\:]+)\]\s*(?P<Event>[\w]+).+?\[(?P<SSID>[\w]+)\].+?\[(?P<APname>[\w\-0-9]+)\@(?P<APmac>[\w\:0-9]+)\].+?\[(?P<sessiontime>[\w\.]+)\s*.+?\].+?\[(?P<rxbytes>[0-9a-zA-Z]+)\].+?\[(?P<txbytes>[0-9a-zA-Z]+)\]'

matches = re.findall(regex, text)

for match in matches:
    for var in match:
        print(var, end=",\t")
    print()
```